# Finding likely locations in Xamarin using google maps API

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mapkit

I am working on a Xamarin iOS project trying to display a list of the most likely locations based on the user's GPS coordinates using either the Place Picker or GMSPlacePickerViewController from the google maps API, as shown in this [Swift tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/current-place-tutorial#get-the-code).
However I can't seem to find any decent tutorials using C#. I don't want to display the map to users I simply want to retrieve the list of most likely locations based on the coordinates.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated as I'm at a bit of a loss about how to use the google maps API to achieve this.

Comment: Have you read this article ?https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/controls/ios_maps/

Answer (score 0):

Okay answering this for anyone coming after me and trying to do something similar.After lots of searching I have realised it is possible to use the nearbySearch method from the Google Places API Web Service to retrieve a list of addresses near particular coordinates within a specific radius (in metres). You can **optionally** specify the type of addresses you are searching for, e.g. Restaurants. 
Not sure how I missed this but there is a Place Search demo at the bottom of this page;

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/